# How to limit provision to node in OpenShift Ansible project

Tags: ansible, openshift, openshift-origin

Given the OpenShift Ansible project https://github.com/openshift/openshift-ansible I was wondering how provision can be limited to a certain node

I use command below to run provision for all nodes in my inventory file

```
ansible-playbook playbooks/deploy_cluster.yml
```

To save time for certain changes I want to limit provision to certain node. I tried for example `limit`

```
ansible-playbook playbooks/deploy_cluster.yml --limit master0
```

Using this specific command I noticed that provisioning is done fundamentally different. For example console will show

```
INSTALLER STATUS ***************************************************************************************************************************************************
Initialization             : Complete (0:00:01)
Health Check               : Complete (0:00:00)
etcd Install               : Complete (0:00:00)
Master Install             : Complete (0:00:00)
Master Additional Install  : Complete (0:00:00)
Node Install               : Complete (0:00:01)
Hosted Install             : Complete (0:00:01)
Web Console Install        : Complete (0:00:00)
Service Catalog Install    : Complete (0:00:00)
```

But in fact nothing is provisioned. Etcd install for example is "complete" but no etcd service is present / installed on the node.

I noticed also warnings appearing in the task responsible for provisioning etcd install

```
TASK [Set etcd install 'In Progress'] ******************************************************************************************************************************
Thursday 28 June 2018  08:48:19 +0000 (0:00:00.270)       0:00:01.344 ********* 
ok: [master0]
 [WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: oo_first_etcd
```

What is the correct / better Ansible way to limit provision to certain node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I remember, master and etcd host group is required at least. The node hosts can add after completing master and etcd installation. But it’s problematic as installation based on node units.  As of v3.9, you can install openshift using partial playbooks.

https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/install_config/install/advanced_install.html#running-the-advanced-installation-individual-components